# I want to create headings relative to a single point from a list of points with angles between the points. Is there a function for this?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of points and their angles relative to each other from one central point. Because of how the list is generated there is no order to the list nor is there a guarantee that an angle between two points will or will not exist. There is also no way of guaranteeing that the angle is clockwise or anticlockwise.

The nested list or 2D numpy array will look something like this:

```
angle_array = 
[[A, B, 32]
[C, B, 37]
[A, D, 117]
[F, E, 84]
[A, F, 103]
[D, E, 56]]
```

Where the "columns" of the list are `[Point 1, Point 2, Angle between 1 and 2]`

Which is created from a cluster of points something like this (sorry crappy mobile phone pic & engineer scratching):

[image: Crappy drawing of what I am trying to find]

I want to end up with a list like this:

```
direction_list = 
[[A,0]
[B,32]
[C,69]
[D,117]
[E,173]
[F,257]]
```

Where the "columns" in this case are `Point, heading relative to point A`

This is only an example and point A does not have to be heading point, it could be any point in the cluster.

Is there a numpy or python function that will loop through a list and create a new list of values based on common values in a list that I could use in this case?

Comment: There is no guarantee of a unique solution here - consider `[[A, B, 90], [C, D, 90]]`. Or even any solution at all: `[[A, B, 90], [B, C, 90], [C, A, 90]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be made into a graph theory problem: given a list of nodes and edges, calculate the distance between them based on the edge plus the distance from the starting node to the current edge. The orientation can be encoded by making the graph directed.

In the above example, it's assumed you want to rotate around in a clockwise orientation (I assume this because the angle between `A` and `F` is 257, not 103). Hence, in this orientation, there is no edge between `A` and `F`. We can encode our graph as follows:

```
graph = {'A': [('B', 32), ('D', 117)],
         'B': [('C', 37)],
         'C': [('D', 48)],
         'D': [('E', 56)],
         'E': [('F', 84)],
         'F': [('A', 103)]}
```

We then do what is effectively a breadth-first search, adding edges when we find them. Note that this doesn't do any error checking; any non-connected graph will simply crash with a `KeyError`. The error checking shouldn't be difficult to add, however:

```
import queue

def calculate_distances(graph, start):
    q = queue.Queue()
    distances = {start: 0}

    for adj in graph[start]:
        distances[adj[0]] = adj[1]
        q.put(adj[0])

    while not q.empty():
        next_node = q.get()
        for adj in graph[next_node]:
            if adj[0] not in distances:
                distances[adj[0]] = adj[1] + distances[next_node]
                q.put(adj[0])
    return sorted([[x, y] for x, y in distances.items()], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Testing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dist = calculate_distances(graph ,'A')
    print(dist)

>>> [['A', 0], ['B', 32], ['C', 69], ['D', 117], ['E', 173], ['F', 257]]
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to create the dictionary of angles for each point? Get a list of unique nodes then for each node iterate through the list of angles and find where it occurs?

Comment: @markmcmurray Well, as I said, orientation makes it a bit harder as (in the example) you have to remove the `A-F` edge due to going through the angles clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph problem.

Each pair in your original list is can be viewed as an edge.

Construct a graph from this list, then run a depth first search.

Begin with a random node with the absolute angle set to zero. When you traverse an edge in the downward direction, add the angle associated with that edge to the current absolute angle. In the upward direction, subtract the edge's angle. After a node has been visited, mark it and do not visit it again.

If the graph is connected, then this procedure should associate an absolute angle to each node. Otherwise, you will have to attempt to restart the DFS at each node in the graph to obtain disconnected sets of absolute angles.

If some absolute angles are negative, just subtract the minimum angle from the entire list of absolute angles.